# Python script Tkinter TclError

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

Trying to run the following on a Raspberry Pi
from
[Mouse Position Python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925599/mouse-position-python-tkinter)

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))

root.bind('<Motion>', motion)
root.mainloop()
```

but get the following error

_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Can any Python experts suggest a solution?

Comment: Found my answer, http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=35995programs that use GUIs cant be started from SSH terminal, either start it on the raspberry pi or through vnc server

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: in addition for the above to work I need to launch the desktop environment