# Python- detecting mouse coordinates OUTSIDE of any desktop environment

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am using the following script
[Mouse Position Python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925599/mouse-position-python-tkinter)

to successfully print out my mouse coordinates on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. However, for the script to work I have to run it from the GUI. IS there any way for a Python script running outside of any desktop environment, to detect mouse coordinates and mouse clicks?

Answer (score 0):

try using pygame and set videolibrary to dummy before pygame.init():

```
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
```

this *might* work, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with module `curses` - it is made to work in terminal.

I found this example

```
import curses 

screen = curses.initscr() 
#curses.noecho() 
curses.curs_set(0) 
screen.keypad(1) 
curses.mousemask(1)

screen.addstr("Example\n\n") 

while True:
    event = screen.getch() 
    if event == ord("q"): 
        break 
    if event == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
        _, mx, my, _, _ = curses.getmouse()
        screen.addstr( '%d %d\n' % (mx, my) )

curses.endwin()
```

Comment: All I see is 'Example' when i run this...no mouse coordinates.

Comment: I forgot to say - click mouse.

Comment: :) Yes I figured as much, still nada. Maybe something to do with mousemask?

Comment: Let's try `screen.addstr()` in place of `print()` - see answer again. Does program end working when you press `q` on keyboard ? I test it with Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.3.2 but only on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu/Debian)