# turtle - How to get mouse cursor position in window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouse, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How would I go about finding the current position of the mouse pointer in the turtle screen? I want it so I have the mouse position before I click and while im moving the cursor. I have searched google and this website can't find anything besides how to get the position after a click.

Comment: Are you using Python's [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html) module? If so, have you had a look at ["Using Events"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#using-events) in the documentation?

Comment: Yes. It only has events for onClick, click drag, on click release. I need it to listen for the location of the mouse pointer.

Comment: Getting the mouse coordinates in the turtle screen is all i ask. So i can make the turtle rotate and look at the mouse.

Answer (score 10):

[`turtle.getcanvas()`](https://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html#turtle.getcanvas) returns a Tkinter Canvas.

[Like with a Tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925599/mouse-position-python-tkinter), you can get the current mouse pointer coordinates by `winfo_pointerx` and `.winfo_pointery` on it:

```
canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
x, y = canvas.winfo_pointerx(), canvas.winfo_pointery()
# or
# x, y = canvas.winfo_pointerxy()
```

If you want to only react to movement instead of e.g. polling mouse pointer positions in a loop, register an event:

```
def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
canvas.bind('<Motion>', motion)
```

Note that events only fire while the mouse pointer hovers over the turtle canvas.

All these coordinates will be window coordinates (with the origin `(0, 0)` at the top left of the turtle window), not turtle coordinates (with the origin `(0, 0)` at the canvas center), so if you want to use them for turtle positioning or orientation, you'll have to do some transformation.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35735400/6243352), here's an example of one way to normalize the Tkinter coordinates for turtle using the `canvas.bind('<Motion>', motion)` approach (`canvas.winfo_pointerxy()` didn't provide values that made sense to me, although I didn't look into it much):

```py
import turtle


def on_motion(event):
    x = event.x - turtle.window_width() / 2
    y = -event.y + turtle.window_height() / 2
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.stamp()
    print(x, y)


turtle.tracer(0)
turtle.penup()
turtle.getcanvas().bind("<Motion>", on_motion)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Using this in a real-time app rather than only on motion:

```py
import turtle


def on_motion(event):
    global mouse_x, mouse_y
    mouse_x = event.x - turtle.window_width() / 2
    mouse_y = -event.y + turtle.window_height() / 2


def tick():
    print(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    turtle.goto(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    turtle.stamp()
    win.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)


turtle.tracer(0)
mouse_x, mouse_y = 0, 0
turtle.getcanvas().bind("<Motion>", on_motion)
turtle.shape("circle")
turtle.penup()
frame_delay_ms = 1000 // 30
win = turtle.Screen()
tick()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Putting it into a more full-featured app without `global`:

```py
import turtle
from math import sin


def add_mouse_listener():
    def on_motion(event):
        nonlocal x, y
        x = event.x - turtle.window_width() / 2
        y = -event.y + turtle.window_height() / 2

    turtle.getcanvas().bind("<Motion>", on_motion)
    x, y = 0, 0
    return lambda: (x, y)


def color(c, a):
    return sin(c + a) / 2 + 0.5


def colors(r, ra, g, ga, b, ba):
    return color(r, ra), color(g, ga), color(b, ba)


def main():
    ra = 0
    ba = 0
    ga = 0
    r = 0.5
    b = 0
    g = 1
    frame_delay_ms = 1000 // 30
    turtle.tracer(0)
    turtle.pensize(40)
    mouse_pos = add_mouse_listener()
    win = turtle.Screen()

    def tick():
        nonlocal ra, ba, ga
        turtle.color(colors(r, ra, g, ga, b, ba))
        ra += 0.03
        ba += 0.0311
        ga += 0.032
        x, y = mouse_pos()
        turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x, y))
        turtle.forward(10)
        turtle.update()
        win.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)

    tick()
    turtle.exitonclick()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```