# Is there a function that returns the mouse position using the turtle module?

Tags: python

This is a simple question and I'm not sure if it belongs here, but I'm wondering if there is a function used to return the mouse coordinates in the turtle module(x, y). I'm using trinket.io and can not install any modules other than the default modules, and I can't find any other way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python(Turtle Module) - Mouse Cursor Position in Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732851/pythonturtle-module-mouse-cursor-position-in-window)

Comment: That answer isn't compatible with trinket.io

Comment: How does `turtle` work on `trinket.io`? It depends on a graphics library to do its drawing and the main point of that answer is that `turtle` itself doesn't have this functionality but it is able to get you access to the canvas of the underlying library.