# How to get coordinates of current mouse position in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-turtle

I want to make a program using Python Turtle, that moves the turtle to mouse coordinates while clicking. But I don't know how to write a function that returns mouse position.
Or, if it will be more understandable, there is HTML and JavaScript code to convert into Python code:

```
function getcoords(event)
{
  console.log(event.clientX + " " + event.clientY);
}

addEventListener("click", getcoords)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35735400/14234613) answer, you can use the code below:

```
canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
x, y = canvas.winfo_pointerx(), canvas.winfo_pointery()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python logic is pretty much the same as your Javascript logic:

```
from turtle import Screen

def getcoords(x, y):
    print(x, y)

screen = Screen()

screen.onclick(getcoords)

screen.mainloop()
```