# How do I find the position of the mouse on the turtle window without needing a button press

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to re-create Connect 4, and I want a pointer that hovers over the mouse to let the player know what column they're dropping the piece into.

I've found solutions for finding the mouse anywhere on the screen, but I want to transfer that to the coordinates on the turtle window wherever it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [turtle - How to get mouse cursor position in window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732851/turtle-how-to-get-mouse-cursor-position-in-window)