# How can i constantly get my mouse position outside of Tkinter window with Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to constantly get my mouse position and print it with Python? I know that with Tkinter you can achieve that by binding mouse motion with something like this, but i want something that also works outside of Tkinter created windows

```
def motion(event):
    posx, posy = pyautogui.position()
    print("PosX = " + str(posx) + " PosY = " + str(posy))
root.bind('<Motion>', motion)
```

Edit: Thanks for the answers but i wasn't so clear in my question, i need a way it works on background while i can use other methods on my code. If i use **while True** i will be locked within this method. I need something exactly like `root.bind('<Motion>', motion)` but that works outside of root window, for example.

Comment: might help - mouse position https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925599/mouse-position-python-tkinter

Comment: There is no way to do this with tkinter alone.

Comment: @BryanOakley there is no problem, i used a Tkinter example because was easier to show what i needed, but i am open to other libraries/solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it by using the [pyxhook](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook) library (implementation of [pyhook](https://pypi.org/project/pyHook/) for Linux). By using this solution you will not have the disadvantage that you are locked on a `while True` loop. To stop the capture just press 'Esc' (event.Ascii == 27).

```
import pyxhook
import pyautogui

def mouse_event(event):
    posx, posy = pyautogui.position()
    print ("PosX: " + str(posx) + ", PosY: " + str(posy))

def cancel_hookmanager(event):
    if event.Ascii == 27:
        hookman.cancel()

hookman = pyxhook.HookManager()
hookman.MouseMovement = mouse_event
hookman.KeyUp = cancel_hookmanager
hookman.HookKeyboard
hookman.HookMouse
hookman.start()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `after()` and `winfo_pointerxy()` to get the mouse position constantly:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, width=20)
lbl.pack()

def get_mouse_pos():
    lbl.config(text='{}, {}'.format(*root.winfo_pointerxy()))
    root.after(100, get_mouse_pos)

get_mouse_pos()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in **very simple** way. You will need pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    print(pyautogui.position())
```

Output :

```
Point(x=708, y=380)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import struct
import binhex

# You'll need to find the name of your particular mouse to put in here...
file = open("/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Trackball-event-mouse","rb")


while True:
     byte = file.read(16)
#    h = ":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in byte)
#    print "byte=",h

    (type,code,value) =  struct.unpack_from('hhi', byte, offset=8)

    if type == 1 and value == 1:
        if code == 272:
            print ("LEFT PRESS")
        if code == 273:
            print("RIGHT PRESS")

    if type == 2:
        if code == 0:
            print("MOVE L/R",value)
        if code == 1:
            print("MOVE U/D",value)
```