# How to draw a square on canvas when he user clicks 2 locations with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am writing an app where the user can "paint" a canvas and now I want to add support for shapes. 
I have a canvas called paint_canvas and I want to draw a shape between the 2 points the user clicks

```py
def draw_square(event):
    x1 = event.x
    y1 = event.y
    # now I want to get the next two points the user clicks
    # how???????
paint_canvas = Canvas(root)
paint_canvas.bind('<Button-3>', draw_square)
```

Comment: Do you want to draw when the user presses a mouse button, drags, and then releases? Or, do you want the user to click, move the mouse, and then click a second time?

Answer (score 0):

You can make two events,
One for the press event ans one for release.
In the first event you store x and y mouse position in another scope (startx , starty)

And in the second event you store mouse position store x and y mouse position in another scope (endx, endy) and then draw your shape with this coordinates

See : https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-16-sect-9.html

And : https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/how+to+draw+rectangle+in+tkinter

If you want to show your rect animation you can use Motion events
[Mouse Position Python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925599/mouse-position-python-tkinter)

Comment: i am looking at the first link you suggested. should I use button-release event?

Comment: Yes in your case  ButtonRelease-3

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to work with double-events. You can just as well store the previously clicked coordinates and draw a rectangle (and reset the previously stored coordinates) as soon as you have two clicks:

```
from tkinter import *


def draw_square(event):
    x1 = event.x
    y1 = event.y
    w = event.widget ## Get the canvas object you clicked on
    if w.coords == None:
        w.coords = (x1,y1)
    else:
        w.create_rectangle(w.coords[0],w.coords[1],x1,y1,fill="#ff0000")
        w.coords = None

root = Tk()
paint_canvas = Canvas(root,width=400,height=400,bg="#ffffff")
paint_canvas.pack()
paint_canvas.bind('<Button-3>', draw_square)
paint_canvas.coords=None

root.mainloop()
```

You could even create a temporary point to mark the first click, which may then be removed as soon as you hit the second one. This point (`w.temp` in the example below) can also be an attribute of the canvas, so you can access it easily via the click:

```
def draw_square(event):
    x1 = event.x
    y1 = event.y
    w = event.widget ## Get the canvas object you clicked on
    if w.coords == None:
        w.coords = (x1,y1)
        w.temp = w.create_oval(x1-1,y1-1,x1+1,y1+1,fill="#00ff00")
    else:
        w.create_rectangle(w.coords[0],w.coords[1],x1,y1,fill="#ff0000")
        w.delete(w.temp)
        w.coords = None
```