# Python: How do I create something that will show the coordinates of my screen when I click?

Tags: python

I’ve been trying to create a cool auto clicker as a little project. How exactly can I create something that will tell me what my mouse coordinates are when I click?

Comment: Short answer is you probably can't without a 3rd party library. It's entirely dependent on the platform you're targeting

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925599/mouse-position-python-tkinter

Comment: how about [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - it can show you mouse current position and even send mouse click to window - so you can create autoclicker.

Comment: how about [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) - `mouse.Listener` may show position, `mouse.Controler` can send click to window.

Comment: `PyAutoGUI` and [Programming a Bot to Play the "Sushi Go Round" Flash Game](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/17/programming-a-bot-to-play-the-sushi-go-round-flash-game/)