# Pysimplegui - highlight on mouse hover

Tags: python, pysimplegui

With Pysimplegui, is it possible to highlight rows in a table on mouse hover?  For example with the following code of my attempt, it highlights on mouse click, but not hover.  Thanks.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = [
    ['John', 25, 'Engineer'],
    ['Alice', 30, 'Designer'],
    ['Bob', 28, 'Developer'],
]

# Define the table layout
layout = [
    [
        sg.Table(
            values=data,
            headings=['Name', 'Age', 'Occupation'],
            display_row_numbers=True,
            auto_size_columns=False,
            justification='left',
            key='-TABLE-'
        )
    ]
]

def on_hover(event, table):
    row = event['row']
    if row is not None:
        table.highlight(row)

window = sg.Window('Hover Highlight Example', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    if event == '-TABLE-':
        on_hover(event, values, window['-TABLE-'])

window.close()
```

Comment: I found with Google: [Enhancement: Check if mouse pointer is hovering element · Issue #2639 · PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/2639).  It suggests to use something like `window['-TEXT-'].bind('<Enter>', '+MOUSE OVER+')` but I think it would need to `bind` this to every row separatelly - but I don't know how to access every row to bind it.

Comment: maybe it would need to `bind` mouse motion and check mouse position to calculate row.

Comment: [Mouse coordinates on Python with PySimpleGUI - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75503832/mouse-coordinates-on-python-with-pysimplegui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using tkinter call

- Set the appearance for item with tag, like 'Highlight'.
- Binding the event `'<Motion>'` to Table element.
- Get the row item by call method `identify_row` with position `event.y`.
- Removes the specified tag, 'Highlight', from each of the listed items.
- Adds the specified tag, 'Highlight', to each of the listed items.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = [
    ['John', 25, 'Engineer'],
    ['Alice', 30, 'Designer'],
    ['Bob', 28, 'Developer'],
]

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
layout = [
    [
        sg.Table(
            values=data,
            headings=['Name', 'Age', 'Occupation'],
            display_row_numbers=True,
            auto_size_columns=False,
            justification='left',
            select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE,
            key='-TABLE-'
        )
    ]
]

def on_hover(event):
    tree = event.widget
    item = tree.identify_row(event.y)
    # There's no methods, tag_remove and tag_add, in tkinter.
    tree.tk.call(tree, "tag", "remove", "Highlight")
    tree.tk.call(tree, "tag", "add", "Highlight", item)

window = sg.Window('Hover Highlight Example', layout, finalize=True)
table = window['-TABLE-']
table.widget.tag_configure('Highlight', background='blue')
table.bind("<Motion>", "Motion")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    if event == '-TABLE-Motion':
        on_hover(table.user_bind_event)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment:  wow!  That's incredible.