# python: finding the active window without the script becoming the active one

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pdf, windows-7-x64

I need to get the file name of an opened PDF in acrobat. Since script doesn’t know the PDF path it needs to find the title of the active window.

I found this script on [Obtain Active window using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python) :

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow 

print GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
```

It's working *but* since I'm starting the script as a keyboard shortcut, *the active window changes: it switches from acrobat to python*. The active window is not anymore the pdf opened in acrobat but the shortcut that launches the script.

So the script print `"script.py"`, instead of the `"my pdf.pdf-adobe acrobat"`

Any idea how to solve this?