# How to open Tkinter window on current monitor (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, multiple-monitors

I'm not sure it's possible to do this, but is there any way for Tkinter to know which monitor you are currently using (in a multiple-monitor setup)?

I might be running with my laptop and external monitor, and run a script from either screen. Ideally, the Tkinter window generated by that script would open on the screen I'm currently working on.

I know how to set the geometry to force the window to open on the main monitor or on a secondary monitor, but I'm wondering if there's a way to figure out which is currently being used.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, check this answer out ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36419702/8150371

Comment: Thank you! This helps me figure out which program is currently being used. Is there a way to figure out which monitor/screen that program is open on, to open my Tkinter window there?