# Windows - finding the window in focus and handling focus change events

Tags: python, windows, event-handling, focus

I write a python program that should run when a certain window is open and in focus.
For this, I need 2 things:

1. I need to know how to find which window has focus currently.
2. I need to know if there is a focus change event.

Tried using win32api and win32gui with no success.
How can I do it?

Example to clerify - say I want to write "geronimo" every time I focus notepad.

- I run the program (notepad closed, nothing happens)
- I open notepad (it should write geronimo)
- I change focus to chrome (nothing happens)
- I change focus back to notepad (writes geronimo again)

Comment: [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook).

Comment: Similar question: [Obtain Active window using Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

This script tracks the focus of windows, it can be changed to suit the need.
https://gist.github.com/keturn/6695625