# Python check if current window is file explorer (windows)

Tags: python, ctypes, active-window

I am using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355052/8522463) to obtain current window

```
from typing import Optional
from ctypes import wintypes, windll, create_unicode_buffer

def getForegroundWindowTitle() -> Optional[str]:
    hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    length = windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd)
    buf = create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
    windll.user32.GetWindowTextW(hWnd, buf, length + 1) 
    return buf.value if buf.value else None 

print(getForegroundWindowTitle())
    
    output:
        Videos
        git
        Downloads
        Python check if current window is file explorer - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
```

While google chrome tabs can be easily identified using this, problem is there's no way to know whether *Videos, git, Downloads* are windows folder (opened using file explorer).

So, is there a way to get the output in this format `Videos - File Explorer` ?
/ check whether the current window is a windows folder/file explorer window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same Question I modified the Code of Nuno Andre
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572696/2532695

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import psutil

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

h_wnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
pid = wintypes.DWORD()
user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(h_wnd, ctypes.byref(pid))
print(psutil.Process(pid.value).name())
```

This one should do the trick, but you need psutil (pip install psutil).
You should see something like "Explorer.exe" if the active Window is an Explorer-Window.