# GetForegroundWindow without using Python win32gui

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are there any other ways to get the current foregroundwindow without using win32gui(win32gui.GetWindowText (win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()))?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Obtain active window using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python), where the python 3 code only uses the built-in `ctypes` library ([solution from Mitch McMabers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355052/10961342)).

Comment: saw it but that only gets the pid and not the name

Comment: When I tested it, the `buff.value` contains the window name.

Comment: ah worked thanks! do you also happen to know why this must be in utf-8. I am trying to write the output to a file and encode it(something simple like base64). But with utf-8 encoding this is impossible (but the file needs utf-8 to write special characters from buff.value output )

Comment: I am not sure, but I assume that it is because of the `ctypes`. Have you tried it with the `codecs`  ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html)) library?