# Python, pyautogui: how to explicitly for os to find required file/dir?

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui

I am writing Selenium tests and faced an issue when I need to upload an image, but the *input* I want to interact with is hidden from view and doesn't have a '*value*' attribute. So, I decided to **use pyautogui to find and attach image** 'manually'.

**The problem is that I need to use two functions:**

```
pyautogui.write()
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

The last one doesn't wait for the OS to find the needed dir/file. **The question: how to make pyautogui.press('enter') function wait until the file is found by the OS?** Currently it is somehow achieved by time.sleep(), but I don't like this aproach.

*ONLY THE LAST BLOCK OF CODE MATTERS*, so you can skip the rest

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pyautogui
import os
from time import sleep

# set up 
chrome_service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

# find the required element
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.online-image-editor.com/")
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn_upload > span")
element.click() # This opens the windows file selector

# find image on my pc like "home/uploads/test_image.jpeg"
JPEG = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "uploads/test_image.jpeg"))

# split path to make it word by word like ["home", "uploads", "test_image.jpeg"]
path = JPEG.split("/")

for word in path:
   sleep(0.2)
   pyautogui.write(word)
   sleep(0.2)
   pyautogui.press("enter")
```

So here if your remove the sleeps, pyautogui.press("enter") doesn't wait unitl the OS finds 'uploads' and just presses enter, which makes the test fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution on **Windows**:

```
while True:
    try:
        pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Open")[0]
        break
    except IndexError:
        pass
pyautogui.write(JPEG)
pyautogui.press("enter")
```

"Open" here is a name of window with file selection

**retry** library can be used instead of while True loop. You can have a look on retry.retry_call function

For **Linux** you can try this one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pyautogui
import os
from time import sleep

import sys
import subprocess
import re

def get_active_window_title():
    root = subprocess.Popen(['xprop', '-root', '_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = root.communicate()

    m = re.search(b'^_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.* ([\w]+)$', stdout)
    if m != None:
        window_id = m.group(1)
        window = subprocess.Popen(['xprop', '-id', window_id, 'WM_NAME'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = window.communicate()
    else:
        return None

    match = re.match(b"WM_NAME\(\w+\) = (?P<name>.+)$", stdout)
    if match != None:
        return match.group("name").strip(b'"')

    return None



# set up
chrome_service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

# find the required element
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.online-image-editor.com/")
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn_upload > span")
element.click() # This opens the windows file selector

# find image on my pc like "home/uploads/test_image.jpeg"
JPEG = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "uploads/test_image.jpeg"))

while True:
    try:
        assert b"Open Files" in get_active_window_title()
        break
    except AssertionError:
        pass
pyautogui.write(JPEG)
pyautogui.press("enter")
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404044/17200418)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! Unfortunatelly I'm a ubuntu user, so: NotImplementedError: PyGetWindow currently does not support Linux.

Comment: I have added Linux solution. You can try it. I have tested it on Ubuntu - works fine

Comment: Thank you for such an excellent answer! You made my day!!