# How can I write a Python script to control Gnome window placement?

Tags: python, desktop, gnome

I'm trying to wrangle my Gnome desktop windows and I would like to automate their placement using Python.  What is a good approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

If you *only* need it to work in an X session, then this is relatively easy to do using xdotool (short summary in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029302/2921914)). You can also use it from Python, as explained in [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681959/how-can-i-use-xdotool-from-within-a-python-module-script).

The Wayland protocol does not allow this by default for security reasons. If you want to be able to support both X and Wayland, you'll have to get to the inner working of GNOME Shell by [writing an extension](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/Writing) (in JS). This extension then either does the moving, or exposes an API to move windows, which you can then call from a Python script.

Comment: That sounds very good!  :-)  Thank you.  This is starting to make sense to me.